# How do I export Notes from iphone to PC with images?

Tags: iphone, notes.app, pc

I have keeping track of my expenses within the notes app on my iPhone. It consists of a series of headings and pictures of receipts for the entire month. How can I get this on my PC in some format with pictures included?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not require your notes to be in Notes format on your PC as well, you can email each note to yourself:

1. Open the Notes app on your iPhone,
2. Get into the note you want to transfer to your PC,
3. Tap the share button (top right),
4. Choose Mail and input your email address,
5. Check the mail on your PC.

You can then copy the contents of the note in the email and paste them into a document for further use or download the attachments to your computer. Some attachments, like photos, may not show in the mail correctly. If that happens, you need to click the show image option (depending on which email service you use) to view the pictures.

These directions have been excerpted from [easeus.com](https://www.easeus.com/iphone-data-transfer/how-to-transfer-notes-from-iphone-to-computer-free.html). Hope they help.

Comment: Hi @Alper, thank you for your response. The issue is that when I attempt to email it to myself the images are added as attachments. I require the images to be in the correct positions within the notes as the receipt images will be cross-referenced with an excel table. Above each image I have added a title and a number uniquely identifying it.

Comment: Not sure which mail client you are using, but try accessing your email through another one if possible. Another (partial) solution could be to put the title and the number of an image in a text box on the image itself via the [picture markup tools](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/draw-in-apps-iph893c6f8bf/13.0/ios/13.0) available in the Notes app on your iPhone. Still, the best solution, in my view, is subscribing to iCloud services even if you only have a Windows computer because you can open your notes via a browser on icloud.com if you subscribe to iCloud. Hope these help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app named [Note2txt](http://note2txt.softwar.io) that will very quickly convert all your notes from the Notes app to text files, but it doesn't include images. The app lets you choose a folder to put all the text files. Then you can copy or email all you wish to a new destination.

If you have images I suggest you look under the file menu item in Notes. There is an option to export a note as a PDF.

Comment: Using Note2txt to convert your notes into text files doesn't include images. I will change my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hi @jmh, thanks for your solution. However, if I attempt to save a Note as a PDF then each image within the note is saved as an individual PDF which for a similar reason to my comment above will not work for me.

Comment: @spenot09  Sorry about that. I thought exporting as PDF would include the image in its appropriate place.

Comment: I cant seem to get around it so will be using another app from now on.